# Firebase Authentication Using JWT token in ReactJS App

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I currently have a frontend (ReactJS) and backend (Django) completely running. I am now looking into real-time updates for certain parts of my application and I have decided to go with Firebase because it allows me to deploy quickly and scale easily later on.

However, as I already have an entire backend setup, which authenticates the user and sends back a token (JWT), I would like to know how I can use the same authentication for Firebase. The idea would be to set custom rules in Firebase based on the userID, and to use this userID (which is just a regular id, e.g. my userID is 1, not a UUID) to create collections inside the real-time database and Firestore.

I have already read the docs on custom tokens, but I haven't understood it properly.

Can I use this to sign a user in, without using Firebase Auth? Or will this create a user in Firebase Auth too?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a [Firebase Auth custom authentication provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) if you want to use your own user auth system with Firebase Auth, in order to use security rules.  Your users will have to be signed in with Firebase Auth client SDK in order for this to work correctly, and [your backend will need to produce a JWT](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).  The linked documentation should have everything you need to get started.  If you are confused about something, please ask a new question that describes **in detail** where you are stuck with your implementation.

Comment: 'Firebase Auth custom authentication provider '  documentation told me to copy the  Private Key file into the authentication server. But I have no access on backend server-side code.

Comment: If you don't have support from your backend on this, it won't be possible to implement.

Comment: How Can i initialize SDK in my React app?